# getting values of of a form in Backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm thinking of migrating an app that was written in jQuery to Backbone and am testing a few pieces. I'm having problems with getting the values of a form and am following various sources which might be outdated or different techniques.

Here is what I have and I have commented on the main issue which is binding the form from this view. But it could just be a simple syntax issue. Specifically the line `var inputLongitude=$input.attr('longitude');`  isn't working. I am trying to get the longitude value but just not working. I'm also not sure if it should be e.target or e.currentTarget (or neither since the only thing working is jQuery). Any help with fixing this would be greatly appreciated. How would I get the longitude value from my form?

```
// no form tags on this piece
<input type='text' id='phone' />
<input type='text' id='longitude' name='longitude' />
<button class='submit-detail'>submit</submit>

var LocationDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {'click .submit-detail':'submitModel', 'change input':'input_change'},
  initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'input_change');
  },
  render: function(){
  .... // form is in here as a string
  },
  input_change: function(e){
    var $input=$(e.currentTarget);
    var inputLongitude=$input.attr('longitude');    // this doesn't work and I'm trying to get to work
    var inputPhone=$input.attr('phone');
    var inputPhone=$('#phone').val();

    console.log("input was changed" + inputLongitude);  // get undefined
    console.log("input was changed" + inputPhone);  // this works fine

  }
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input has neither `longitude` nor `phone` attribute. 
I guess you need to get values of those fields.

```
$("#longitude").val(); //longitude value
$("#phone").val(); //phone value
```

1. You get element (field) by its id. `$("#field_id")` - create jquery wrapped around HTMLElement with id == field_id.
2. Extract its value by calling `val()`.

Comment: thx, it seems like I'd rather make input have these attributes, right? Isn't that more canonical backbone? I do mostly server dev so just trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: @timpone That wouldn't help much. Those attributes wont be updated when user change values in inputs. I do recommend you to read this http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html 
Backbone doesn't have built in bidirectional databinding. If you are looking for a framework that automagically binds inputs to js-models take a look at Knockout.